# How to express this summation?

Tags: matrices, summation, index-notation

I have an array with coordinates i and j. For every point, I have a scalar property. I want to express the summation of this scalar property, let's say I want this value for point (3,4) and that i and j go from 1 to 5. I'm a bit confused on how to express it because if I simply put:
\begin{equation}
D_{(i,j)}=\sum_{\substack{i,j=1}}^{m} (2^{2k_{i,j}}) - 2^{2k_{i,j}}
\end{equation}
or even if I write:
\begin{equation}
D_{(i,j)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^{m} (2^{2k_{i,j}}) - 2^{2k_{i,j}}
\end{equation}

That's not what I try to say. Because if i goes from 1 to 5, but the point I want to calculate is located at i=3 and j=4. So it doesn't make sense that m=3 and n=4, because for the first three rows of the array, I need to make a summation for i=5.

I need another way to express that and it can be also in index notation. I just don't know how to do it.

Example:
Let's say I have this matrix $E$:
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
4 & 1 & 3 & 5\\
7 & 3 & 2 & 9\\
5 & 2 & 8 & 4
\end{bmatrix}

I need to calculate a variable for each element, let's call this variable $p$.

$p$ is equal to the summation of all the elements of this matrix $E$ that are located before the position I'm trying to calculate, minus the value of $E$ at that position. For the element located at row 2 and column 3, which is equal to 3, that would be $p_{(2,3)} = 2+3+4+1+4+1+3 - 3$

So I want to be able to express that summation!

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  $2^{2k_{i,j}} - 2^{2k_{i,j}} = 0$.  You mention the point (3,4) but that doesn't come in to your equation anywhere.  There's not much reason to include this equation anyway, since you say it is wrong.

Comment: I think you are overloading your variables $i,j$.  You should use some different dummy variables for indexing the sum.

Comment: Yes, you are right in the point of using different variables and not i and j. I know it's a bit confusing my question. How would you express the summation of the elements of a matrix, when both indexes are not the same? That's why I said "point (3,4)", I meant the element located at the row 3 and the column 4 of an array (in the example an array of 5 x 5).

Comment: By the way, the expresion is not equal to 0, because the first side is the summation of all the elements from i and j = 1, to i and j equal to (3,4), respectively. That's my question, how to properly express the summation of the elements of a matrix when you don't want to sum all the elements and the indexes are not the same.

Comment: You need to use different variables then.  Like $(\sum_{\substack{i,j=1}}^{m} 2^{2k_{i,j}}) - 2^{2k_{r,s}}$ where $(r,s)$ = $(3,4)$.

Comment: What you want might be clearer if you [edit] the question to show us a complete small sample matrix of values and an explicit calculation (without $\Sigma$s) of a sum you are interested in. (Do not try to do this in a comment.)

Comment: I already edited the question and added a short example, it's not a 5 x 5 matrix, but I think it's enough to clarify my question.

Comment: Jair Taylor but that won't solve my problem, because what value is supposed to take m? If m should take the value of 5 for the first three rows and 3 for the 4th row. Do you know what I mean? I can't simply use m!